# Ways to see notifications besides pull down bar

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc, notification-bar, htc-one-x

The notification status pull down bar is not working because the very upper part of the screen seems damaged (verified running diagnostics that pixels there are not active). 
1) Can I see the notifications some other way?
2) Can I assume that screen replacement solves this?
Htc one X phone

Comment: As a temporary solution you can use any launcher application with gesture support or notification apps like Floatify, NiLS etc. You should customize them for proper usage.

Comment: @MANI:I assume the permanent solution is screen replacement. Is the replacement an on the spot operation? I don't want to leave my phone to a store

Comment: Well that depends on busyness of the store. They might keep your mobile for a day or two. You can trust them if it's an authorized store. Else there are unauthorized stores who does the job on spot but everything is non-branded there.

Comment: @MANI: I don't care about brand as long as it works and they don't access my data. The phone itself is not new and I want to avoid buying a new phone for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a third party launcher you can use gestures for certain functions.
For instance, using Nova Launcher Prime, when I swiped down anywhere on my home screen it would bring down my notifications.
So that could solve that issue for you.

There should be other free alternatives that perform the same function

To answer your last question, a screen replacement should fix the issue though.

Comment: What is the meaning of the icons in your sentence "there should be other free alternatives...."

Comment: @smith it's a thumbs up. Didn't know emojis didn't work here sorry.

Comment: I installed a launcher and solved it. It is not possible to push the overflow bar of any app also. Can a launcher fix that too? Also is a a screen replacement a 5 secs operation? I don't want to leave my phone to a store